# Writing to HTML tag from external file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am brand new to HTML, CSS and Javascript. I have a set of HTML links, which each represent an email. Upon clicking a link, I want the email to be displayed in a div (within a

tag). The content of the email is in a separate text file. I have about 40 links. For example, one link would be:

```
    <a class="emailrefs" href="#" onclick="emailDisplay('164611092012')">11 September 2012 16:46</a>
```

And my Javascript is:

```
    <script>
    function emailDisplay(date)
    {
        if (date==164611092012)
            {
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="This worked";
            } 
    }
    </script>
```

Inside the if loop, I want code that will read from an external text file, and write to a

tag in a div on my page.

I hope this all makes sense. As I say, I am brand new to this, started literally a week ago and worked very hard to learn!

Thanks!

MiddleClassMan

Comment: you will need to look in to ajax ( maybe with jquery ) to retrieve the content of the separate files , these must be on the same domain. But your question really is to general to give a concrete answer, can you give more information about the context of this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into jQuery for file manipulation and reading, as JavaScript doesn't really do much file handling other than XML: $(".content").load("file.html");

Comment: Thanks for that! I will have a look then. Have not worked with JQuery before, but if that is the way to go, I will try to learn!

Comment: Tempted to -1 this answer but jQuery is a decent place to start. The rest however is bunk: jQuery /is/ javascript, XML is nothing more than formatted plaintext and JS can handle binary just fine with a bit of work.  See for example JS/Linux http://bellard.org/jslinux/